# How to configure backpreasure in Spark 3 Structure Stream Kafka/Files source with Trigger.Once option

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

[In Spark 3 Behave of backpressure option on Kafka and File Source for trigger.once scenario was changed](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/27380).

But I have a question.
How can I configure backpressure to my job when I want to use TriggerOnce?

In spark 2.4 I have a use case, to backfill some data and then start the stream.
So I use trigger once, but my backfill scenario can be very very big and sometimes create too big a load on my disks because of shuffles and to driver memory because FileIndex cached there.
SO I use max `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` and `maxFilesPerTrigger` to control how much data my spark can process. that's how I configure backpressure.

And now you remove this ability, so assume someone can suggest a new way to go?

Answer (score 1):

`Trigger.Once` ignores these options right now (in Spark 3), so it always will read everything on the first load.

You can workaround that - for example, you can start stream with trigger set to periodic, with some value like, 1 hour, and don't execute `.awaitTermination`, but have a parallel loop that will check if first batch is done, and stop the stream.  Or you can set it to continuous mode, and then check if batches having 0 rows, and then terminate the stream.  After that initial load you can switch stream back to Trigger.Once

Comment: it's a very dirty solution, bring some multithread complexity to my code.
I also can throw exceptions on every second batch and handle stream shutdown on this specific exception. But still I expect to learn how to do it without HACKs.

Comment: I can't believe that Spark developer removes the feature of backpressure for Trigger>once and do not provide any good replacement for it.

Comment: Are you sure that it worked before? In this solution you don't need to do any multithreading, just don't use `awaitTermination`

Comment: I know that dev team is working on that... but don't know in which Spark version it will land

Comment: Previously Trigger.Once just generate a batch. This batch respects all config in the same way as Any other trigger. And now I need to do a dirty hack, to stop when the first batch pass. The main Issue that If I will fail the batch when it already started, offset WAL will be present, this is an issue for me. Because I can't override config for the next batch.

Comment: you're correct, it works just fine in the Spark 2.4... until it's fixed correctly, that workaround is what I can offer...

Comment: Ok, So Databricks does not have any way to control backpressure in trigger.once scenario? And it's `a fix` -> Introduce coupling between scheduling and backpressure options for stream batches?